# About the je in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
77f4bccd 741a            je      SHLWAPI!UrlIsW+0x3d (77f4bce9)
```

According to this formula:

```
7x xx                 RIP=RIP+8 bit displacement
```

The dest address should be `77f4bccd+1a=77F4BCE7`,but it's actually `77f4bce9`.

Why?

**UPDATE**

```
77f4bce2 0f85a20a0000    jne     SHLWAPI!Ordinal152+0x101 (77f4c78a)
```

The dest address should be `77f4bce2+a20a0000=119FEBCE2`,but it's `77f4c78a`,why?

Comment: The displacement is relative to the address after the instruction has been read, i.e. you need to add 2 bytes for the instruction itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset is after the *end* of the current instruction. Since the instruction is encoded in two bytes in this case, you need to add two to your calculation.

Quoting the [AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 3: General-Purpose and System Instructions](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24594.pdf) section 1.7:

> In 64-bit mode, addressing relative to the contents of the 64-bit
>   instruction pointer (program counter)—called RIP-relative
>   addressing or PC-relative addressing—is implemented for
>   certain instructions. In such cases, the effective address is
>   formed by adding the displacement to the 64-bit RIP of the **next
>   instruction**.

(emphasis added)

For the second one, you're reading the offset the wrong byte order (remember that x86 CPUs are little-endian). It's actually `0x00000aa2`. Add the 6 bytes of instruction and the jump does compute to:

```
0x77f4bce2 + 0x0aa2 + 0x06 = 0x77f4c78a
```

Comment: Can you explain the other example above?

Comment: That quote from the manual is about the RIP-relative *data* addressing mode, like `mov eax, [RIP + symbol]` or whatever syntax your assembler uses for address of `foo` wrt. current location.  But yes, exactly the same rule applies for branch targets.  Think of it as RIP while executing an instruction = address of the start of the next.  Historically a simple CPU might finish decoding one instruction (finding the start of the next), then run it with that program counter value.

Answer (score 1):

Because `RIP` is already incremented to point to the next instruction by the time pipeline gets to add the displacement.

Comment: If this example is not obvious,how to explain this one: `77f4bce2 0f85a20a0000    jne     SHLWAPI!Ordinal152+0x101 (77f4c78a)`?

Comment: I think @Mat explained that - the little endian offset of `0xaa2`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the destination address is calculated from the incremented instruction pointer (the address after the `je`) and the displacement.